# MySQL: VIEW Statements: Using Views and Aggregate functions

Tags: mysql, view, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to use a view statement within a select statement, but at the same time I'm attempting to include an aggregate function which includes joins inside of the VIEW table.

What I'm not understanding is whether or not I need to rejoin the other tables. Why doesn't this work while using SalesData as a table?

The error I get is:

> "SQL Error (1054): Unknown column
>   'SalesData.unit_price' in 'field list'

With this, I believe the error actually occurs here:

> SUM(ROUND(SalesData.unit_price * SalesData.order_qty,2)) as 'Total
>   Spent'

```
CREATE VIEW SalesData AS 
    SELECT orders.customer_id, 
           SUM(ROUND(items.unit_price * order_details.order_qty,2)) as 'Total Spent'
    FROM order_details
    JOIN orders on orders.order_id = order_details.order_id
    JOIN items on items.item_id = order_details.item_id
    GROUP BY orders.customer_id;

SELECT CONCAT(customers.customer_first_name, ' ', customers.customer_last_name) as 'Customer',
           SUM(ROUND(SalesData.unit_price * SalesData.order_qty,2)) as 'Total Spent'
    FROM customers
    JOIN SalesData on SalesData.customer_id = customers.customer_id
    GROUP BY customer_id;
```

Comment: Can you try to alias the customer_id, like this? SELECT orders.customer_id AS customer_id

Comment: I can't see how that error is occurring. At no point did you reference `unit_price` qualified to the `SalesData` view - you only use `items.unit_price`.  It's really that SQL statement causing the error?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I've been playing with the code and posted the wrong thing in there. The table I was using previously in the SUM function was SalesData. I will change it. But the same error occurs with this table being used as well. @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: @Minh I tried it, and it didn't change much in the way of our error.

Comment: Ok, so the `SalesData` view only exposes two columns in its `SELECT` list -- `customier_id, Total Spent`. Should it also be including `unit_price, order_quantity` column that you intend to use in the join, or should those be derived from an additional join to `orders` in your final query?

Comment: No, it should only include the customer_id and Total Spent in the select list. At least, that's all I want displayed. The problem is that I'm not sure if they were supposed to include the same joins in the Select statement or not, because they wanted us to join customers separately from the VIEW statement inside the SELECT statement...if that makes any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it doesn't seem that unit_price is a column of SalesData, but looking at your question, it seems that all you need is this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(customers.customer_first_name, ' ', customers.customer_last_name) as 'Customer',
       SalesData.[Total Spent]
FROM customers
JOIN SalesData on SalesData.customer_id = customers.customer_id;
```

Comment: Okay, this gives me questions. In normal standards, if you put a variable as in quotes (like so: customer_id as 'Customer ID') could you put it in something like you did? (SalesData.[Total Spent]  . Is that a typically working thing? Unfortunately, it did not work in mine, but it led me to try other things!!  When I changed SalesData.[Total Spent] to SalesData.Total_Spent (also changing the as statement in the VIEW) it did work. I guess I want to know why it doesn't work the way you did it...

Comment: In SQL Server, we use [ ] to denote a name that possibly contains a space between (as in your case, 'Total Spent'). For Oracle it's replaced by double quotes. So you'll probably need SalesData."Total Spent"